# Mocking models for testing Ember.easyForms input component inside another ember component

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-qunit

I am using ember-cli qunit testing using `moduleForComponent`.  I have the following select element inside an ember component I have created.

```
        {{input site as="select"
            collection="sites"
            selection="site"
            optionLabelPath="content.siteLabel"
            optionValuePath="content.id"
            prompt="Please Select"
            label=" "
        }}
```

The actual `sites` collection is found using the `store`.

```
sites : function() {
    return this.get('store').find('site');
}.property()
```

I am using [jsMockito](http://jsmockito.org/) to mock out the `store`.

```
var siteMock = mock(DS.Model);
when(siteMock).get('id').thenReturn(1);
when(siteMock).get('siteLabel').thenReturn('Qunit');

var storeMock = mock(DS.Store);
when(storeMock).find('site').thenReturn([siteMock]);
```

I pass this into the components as a parameter in the test.

```
var component = this.subject({
    store : storeMock
});
```

The generated html looks like this, it seems that siteMock has rendered but the `optionLabelPath` and `optionValuPath` did not work correctly even though I have added the appropriate expectations on the mock.

```
<select id="ember473" class="ember-view ember-select">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option id="ember491" class="ember-view" value=""></option>
</select>
```

I have tested using the getters on the `siteMock` in the debugger and everything is working as expected.  I guess I need another `when` condition on some property of `siteMock` but I am not sure what.  Can anyone give me some advice on getting this working?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are using `content.` in your paths `optionLabelPath="content.siteLabel"` which is thinking about controller proxing to a model.

But your test are using the models directly -undecorated by a controller- and they do not have a content property.

Comment: Sounds like you are no the right track.  Is there away around this?

Comment: I tried using and ember proxy but it still didn't work. `    var objProxy = Ember.ObjectProxy.create({ content: siteMockMelbourne });
    var arrProxy = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({ content: [objProxy] });`

Comment: Question, are you injecting `store` into the components? or where is `this.get('store').find('site');` placed? from your question seems to be the component, but they generally dont have access to the store

Comment: Yes, I am injecting the store into the component via a parameter called `store`, because as you said, it is not available by default.